# Detecting Single Tap in Screen for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to add a code where when a user tap the screen in his/her screen in android, there will be some dialog box showing that the screen is tapped. i tried few codings but it makes my project crash. any suggestions for coding? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement on the root view an OnClickListener interface.

//TestActivity

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        findViewById(R.id.ll_root).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Screen tapped")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }

}
```

//Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll_root"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This assumes there is nothing on the screen at all?

Comment: This assumes that if that's the case the event must not be consumed for the children views :)

Comment: wow! thanks Valbertos! :) 
and well, i intend to use this to pop up a message on the screen. so there is nothing on the screen :) Nabin

Answer (score 1):

Use `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method.

**From documentation**

```
Implement this method to intercept all touch screen motion events. 
This allows you to watch events as they are dispatched to your children,
and take ownership of the current gesture at any point.
```

**Example:**